# Not able to install xrdp

Tags: 22.04, xrdp

I am not able to install xrdp. It is giving an error saying "no installation candidate" on ubuntu 22.04 latest version.
Kindly help me.

[sudo] password for Satish:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package vnc4server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vnc4server' has no installation candidate
Satish@vmi1502872:~$ vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are performing your installation but normally xRDP does not use anymore vnc4server package.  xRDP software comes with 2 packages xrdp and xorgxrdp package.

The easiest and simple way to install xrdp is simply to run

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Obviously, your system should be up to date as well. If you run this command, it should not ask for vnc4server package but it should tell you about the xorgxrdp package.

If this is still not working, you can try to compile from source.  For that, you can use the script we have written that can ease the installation of xrdp package on Ubuntu systems.

We are assuming that you have a desktop interface running (Gnome Desktop)
To use and obtain our script, use the following commands

```
#Go to your Downloads Folders (as normal user/ no root account)
cd ~/Downloads

#Download the script
wget https://www.c-nergy.be/downloads/xRDP/xrdp-installer-1.4.8.zip

#unzip the package
unzip xrdp-installer-1.4.8.zip

#make it executable
chmod +x xrdp-installer-1.4.8.sh

#execute the script 
./xrdp-installer-1.4.8.sh -c
```

No guarantee that the script will run succesfully and that it will solve your issue but you can always give it a try

Full instructions on how to use and download the script can be found in our blog at
[xRDP – Easy install xRDP on Ubuntu 20.04,22.04,23.XX (Script Version 1.4.8)](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=19228)

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya